# Defining Keras Models for Arrays

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have 3 inputs that will go into my model, They are:
1. 20 X 20 List
2. n numbers of X [2] array or like  [ [a,b], [c,d], ......]
3. [a,b] array

That's it making the model simple but I do not understand how to define the inputs and outputs for this.

The model should have 2 hidden layers of 32 each.

```
    inputBoard = tf.keras.Input(shape=(20,20))
    x1 = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(inputBoard)
    boardDense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(x1)

    inputAgent = tf.keras.Input(shape=(None, 2))
    x2 = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(inputAgent)
    agentDense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu')(x2)

    inputReward = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,1))
    x3 = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(inputReward)
    rewardDense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='relu')(x3)

    concat = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([boardDense, agentDense, rewardDense])

    hidden = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation = 'relu')(concat)
    hidden2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(hidden)

    output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation="softmax")(hidden2)

    self.model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[inputBoard, inputAgent, inputReward], outputs = output)

    self.model.build()
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr = self.learningRate)
    self.model.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer = optimizer)
    self.model.summary()
```

Comment: I am sorry I can not help you by code. Anyway, I think you need to make one input data concatenated by x1, x2 and x3.

Comment: cheers anyway!!